# How to have multiple list react to each other un Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Okay so I have three lists defined as Vue.js components that need to react to each other. Site, profile and Employee. This basically means that when I select a site, I want to load the profiles and the employees of this specific site, so on and so forth. The thing is that I can't figure out how to achieve this. Codewise, here's what I have:

selectw.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
div
    .btn.dropdown-toggle.text-left.btn-block.k-selectbox-toggle(tabindex="0", v-on:keydown.down.stop="selectDown", v-on:keydown.up.stop="selectUp", v-on:keydown.enter="updateClose")
        k-icon(:icon="currentOption.icon||icon||placeholderIcon", v-if="currentOption.icon||icon||(!currentOption.text&&placeholderIcon)")
        span(v-if="currentOption.icon||icon||(!currentOption.text&&placeholderIcon)") &nbsp;
        span(v-html="currentOption.html||currentOption.text||placeholder")
    .dropdown-menu.pre-scrollable(v-if="searchResults.length")
        .search-indicator(hidden v-if="options.length>5")
        .dropdown-header.pr-3.pl-3(v-show="options.length>5")
            input.form-control(type="text", :placeholder='__("Search...")', style="width:100%", v-model="searchText", v-on:keydown.down.stop="selectDown", v-on:keydown.up.stop="selectUp", v-on:keydown.enter.stop="updateClose()")
        //{{__("Search...")}} FIXME because poedit is retarded
        a(v-for="(option,index) in searchResults", :class="'dropdown-item '+(option.id==value?'active':'')", href="#" , v-on:mousedown="update(option.id)")
            k-icon(:icon="option.icon||icon", v-if="option.icon||icon")
            span(v-if="option.icon||icon") &nbsp;
            span(v-html="option.html||option.text")
    .dropdown-menu.pre-scrollable(v-else) 
        .dropdown-item {{__("Empty List")}}
    input(type="hidden", :name="name", :value="value")
</template>

<script>

    var allowClose = true;

    // autofocus search in selectbox dropdowns
    $(document).on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(e){

        var searchInput = $(e.target).find('.search-indicator')

        if(searchInput.length){
            allowClose = false;
            $(e.target).find('.form-control').focus();
        }

    });

    // close on blur
    $(document).on('blur', '.k-selectbox-toggle', function(e){
        var element = $(this);

        if(allowClose){
            setTimeout(a=>{
                element.next().removeClass("show") // WHY DOES THIS WORK ?!?!?!?
            }, 100)
        }
        allowClose = true;
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.k-selectbox-toggle+.dropdown-menu input.form-control', function(e){
        var element = $(this);

        setTimeout(a=>{
            element.parent().parent().removeClass("show") // WHY DOES THIS WORK ?!?!?!?
        }, 100);
    });

    $(document).on('focus','.k-selectbox-toggle', e => {
        $(e.target).dropdown('toggle');
    })

    // mod negative numbers
    var mod = (x, n) => ((x%n)+n)%n;

    export default {
        methods:{
            update(id){
                if(id!==undefined){
                    this.$emit('update:value', id)
                }
            },
            updateClose(e){
                if(this.searchResults[0]&&_.findIndex(this.searchResults, {id:this.value})==-1) this.$emit('update:value', this.searchResults[0].id);

                this.$emit('update:value', this.value);

                $(this.$el).find("input.form-control").blur();
                $(this.$el).find(".k-selectbox-toggle").blur();
            },
            selectDown(e){
                var index = _.findIndex(this.searchResults, {id:this.value});
                if(index==-1)index=-1;
                var length = this.searchResults.length;
                this.value = this.searchResults[(index+1)%length].id;
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            selectUp(e){
                var index = _.findIndex(this.searchResults, {id:this.value});
                if(index==-1)index=1;
                var length = this.searchResults.length;
                this.value = this.searchResults[mod(index-1, length)].id;
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        computed:{
            searchResults(){
                var exclude = this.exclude||[];
                if(exclude[0]&&exclude[0].id){
                    exclude = exclude.map(a=>a.id)
                }
                return this.options.filter(a=>{
                    return _.lowerCase(a.text)
                        .indexOf(
                            _.lowerCase(this.searchText)
                        ) !== -1;
                }).filter(a=>exclude.indexOf(a.id) == -1);
            },
            currentOption(){
                return _.find(this.options, {id:this.value}) || _.find(this.options, {id:-1}) || (this.placeholder?{}:this.options[0]) || {}
            }
        },
        watch:{
            options(){
                $(this.$el).find(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("show")
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

components.js

```
var modelOptions = {
    sites: app.metadata.sites.map(a=>({id:a.id,text:a.name})),
    profiles: app.metadata.profiles.map(a=>(
            {
                id: a.id,
                text: a.name,
                //FIXME add color tags to k-icon
                html: "<span class='color-tag-group'><span data-color="+a.color+" class='color-tag'></span></span> "+a.name
            }
        )
    ),
    employees: app.metadata.employees.map(a=>{
        var colors = a.profiles.map(a=>"<span data-color="+a.color+" class='color-tag'></span>").join("")
        return {
            id: a.id,
            text: a.firstname + " " + a.lastname,
            html: "<span class='color-tag-group'>"+colors+"</span> "+a.firstname+" "+a.lastname
        }
    }),
    weeks:weekList
};

var selectBoxSettings = require("./selectw.vue");

Vue.component('k-combobox', _.assign({}, selectBoxSettings, {
    props:["model", "value", "placeholder", "strict", "name", "exclude", "context"],
    data(){
        var context = this.context || "filter";
        // filter
        // selection

        var options = _.clone(modelOptions[this.model]);
        // var options = null;
        console.log('dsfsdfdsfdsfsd');
        console.log(options);

        var placeholderIcon = "";

        if(this.model=="profiles"){
            placeholderIcon = "profile"
        }

        if (!this.strict){
            if(context=="filter"){
                options.unshift({
                    id: -1,
                    text: app.utils.translate( "All " + _.capitalize(this.model) ),
                    icon: {profiles: "profile", employees:"user"}[this.model]
                });
            }
            if(context=="selection"){
                options.unshift({
                    id: null,
                    text: app.utils.translate( "No " + _.capitalize(this.model).slice(0, -1) ),
                    icon: {profiles: "profile", employees:"user"}[this.model]
                });
            }
        }else{ 
            if(!this.placeholder){
                this.$emit('update:value', this.value||options[0].id);
            }
        }

        var icon = "";

        if(this.model=="sites"){
            icon = "site"
        }

        return {
            options,
            searchText: "",
            placeholderIcon,
            icon
        };
    },
    methods:{
        myTesting(e){console.log("my god")}
    }
}));
```

main.vue

```
<template lang="pug">

div
    .btn-group.mb-3
        k-combobox.btn-group(model="sites", :value.sync="currentSite")
        k-combobox.btn-group(model="profiles", :value.sync="currentProfile")
        k-combobox.btn-group(model="employees", :value.sync="currentEmployee")
        #print-calendar.btn.btn-primary.d-print-none(onclick="window.print()")
            k-icon(icon="print")
            |{{__('Print')}}
    .btn.mb-3
        | {{__("Total:")}}  
        k-duration.d-inline-block(:minutes="totalMinutes")
    br
    div(v-if="!isDay(currentWeek)&&currentSite!=-1")
        .btn-group.mb-3.mr-3
            .btn.btn-primary(v-on:click="copyWeek", v-if="!isDay(currentWeek)") {{__("Copy Selected Week")}}
            .btn.btn-primary(v-on:click="copyWeek", v-else) {{__("Copy Selected Day")}}
        .btn-group(v-if="sourceWeek")
            .btn-group.mb-3(tabindex="0", v-if="weekFuture(currentWeek)&&currentWeek!==sourceWeek")
                .btn.btn-primary(v-on:click="pasteWeek") {{__("Paste")}} {{weekFormat(sourceWeek)}} {{__("Here")}}
            a.btn-group.mb-3(tabindex="0", v-else, style="cursor: not-allowed", data-toggle="popover", :data-content="__('error_week_copy')")
                .btn.btn-primary.disabled {{__("Paste")}} {{weekFormat(sourceWeek)}} {{__("Here")}}

    //{{__("error_week_copy")}}

    .modal(v-if="popupShown", style="display:block", v-on:click="hideModalSafe")
        .modal-dialog.modal-lg(v-on:keydown.enter="syncSchedule()")
            .modal-content
                h3.modal-header {{moment(currentSchedule.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}
                    button.close(type="button",v-on:click="popupShown=false") &times;
                .modal-body
                    .row
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-start") {{__('Start')}}
                            k-input-time(:date.sync="currentSchedule.start")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-end") {{__('End')}}
                            k-input-time(:date.sync="currentSchedule.end")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-pause") {{__('Pause')}}
                            k-input-minutes(:minutes.sync="currentSchedule.pause")
                    .row
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-site-id") {{__('Site')}}
                            k-combobox(model="sites", :value.sync="currentSchedule.site_id", strict="true", "v-on:update:value"="siteUpdateValue")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-profile-id") {{__('Profile')}}
                            k-combobox(model="profiles", :value.sync="currentSchedule.profile_id", context="selection", "v-on:update:value"="profileUpdateValue")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-employee-id") {{__('Employee')}}
                            k-combobox(model="employees", :value.sync="currentSchedule.employee_id", context="selection", "v-on:update:value"="employeeUpdateValue")

                .modal-footer
                    .btn.btn-danger.mr-auto(v-on:click="deleteSchedule()")
                        k-icon(icon="delete")     
                        |  {{__('Remove')}}
                    .btn.btn-primary(v-on:click="syncSchedule()", tabindex="0") {{__('Save')}}
</template>

<script>
var $fullCalendar = {};

export default {
    el: "#vueapp",
    data: app.models.manageSchedules,
    methods:{
        syncSchedule(){
            $fullCalendar.storeEvent(_.clone(this.currentSchedule));
            this.popupShown = false;
        },
        deleteSchedule(){
            var data={
                id: this.currentSchedule.id
            };

            app.ajax.defaultRequest("delete", "/api/fullcalendar/"+data.id, {}, function(response){
                $fullCalendar.removeEvents(data.id);
                $fullCalendar.updateTotalDisplayedTime();
                app.logger.debug("remove event", response);
            });

            this.popupShown = false;
        },
        hideModalSafe(e){
            var $ = window.$;
            if($(e.target).hasClass("modal")){
                this.popupShown = false;
            }
        },
        pasteWeek(){
            var data = _.pick(this, [
                "sourceWeek",
                "currentSite",
                "currentProfile",
                "currentEmployee"
            ]);
            data.destinationWeek = this.currentWeek;

            app.ajax.calendar.copy(data, response=>{
                if(response.success){
                    $fullCalendar.refetchEvents();
                }else{
                    app.models.manageSchedules.layout.ajaxMessage = response.message;
                }
            });
        },
        copyWeek(){
            this.sourceWeek = this.currentWeek
        },
        siteUpdateValue(value)
        {
            var self = this;
            // this.loadContent();
            app.ajax.defaultRequest("post", "/api/profiles", {"site_id": value}, function(response){
                // console.log(response);
                // console.log(app.models.manageSchedules);

                self.$emit('testing', 'blbblbblb');

                //app.metadata.profiles = response.data;

                // app.models.manageProfileIndex.profiles = response.data;
            });
        },
        profileUpdateValue(value)
        {

        },
        employeeUpdateValue(value)
        {

        },
        weekFormat(week){
            var __ = app.utils.translate;
            var [start, end] = week.replace(/\s/g, "").split("@").map(a=>moment(a));

            var humanStart = start.format(__("MMM D"));
            var humanEnd = end.format(__("MMM D"));

            if(humanStart!==humanEnd){
                return __("W") + start.week() //+ " - " + humanStart + " " + __("date_to") + " " + humanEnd;
            }else{
                return humanStart;
            }
        },
        weekFuture(week){
            var timestamp = moment(week.replace(/\s/g, "").split("@")[0]).unix()
            return timestamp > moment().add(app.metadata.server_offset, 'milliseconds').unix() 
        },
        isDay(week){
            var [start, end] = week.replace(/\s/g, "").split("@");
            return start === end;
        }
    },
    watch:{
        currentSite(){
            $fullCalendar.refetchEvents();
            this.sourceWeek = "";
        },
        currentProfile(){
            $fullCalendar.refetchEvents();
        },
        currentEmployee(){
            $fullCalendar.refetchEvents();
        }
    },
    beforeCreate(){

        var model = app.models.manageSchedules;

        _.assign(model,{
            popupShown:false,
            currentSchedule:{
                id: 0,
                title: "",
                start: "",
                end: "",
                pause: "",
                site_id: 0,
                profile_id: -1,
                employee_id: -1
            },
            currentSite: -1,
            currentProfile: -1,
            currentEmployee: -1,
            sourceWeek: "",
            currentWeek: "",
            hasCalendar: true,
            totalMinutes: 0 
        });

        var calendarConfigs = require('../fullcalendarConfigs');
        calendarConfigs = _.assign({},calendarConfigs,require('./configs'));

        calendarConfigs.eventDrop = function (event, delta, revertFunc){
            if(moment(event.start).unix() < moment().add(app.metadata.server_offset,'milliseconds').unix()){
                revertFunc();
                return;
            }
            $fullCalendar.storeEvent(event);
        }

        var $calendar = $('<div class="card mb-3" id="calendar" style="cursor:copy"></div>');
        $calendar.insertAfter($('#vueapp'));

        $calendar.fullCalendar(calendarConfigs);
        $fullCalendar = $calendar.data('fullCalendar');


        $fullCalendar.addEvent = function (event) {

            if(moment(event.start).unix() < moment().add(app.metadata.server_offset,'milliseconds').unix()){
                return;
            }

            app.logger.debug('addEvent', event);

            event.site_id = model.currentSite || app.metadata.sites[0].id;
            event.profile_id = model.currentProfile!=-1 ? model.currentProfile || null : null;
            event.employee_id = model.currentEmployee!=-1 ? model.currentEmployee || null : null;

            this.storeEvent(event);

        };
        //---------------------------------------------------------
        $fullCalendar.storeEvent = function (event) {

            var fullcalendarScope = this;

            app.logger.debug('fullCalendar - storeEvent', event);

            var data = _.pick(event, ["id", "title", "start", "end", "pause", "site_id", "profile_id", "employee_id"])


            if(data.start.local){data.start = data.start.local().format();}
            if(data.end.local){data.end = data.end.local().format();}

            data.type = "calendar";

            app.logger.debug('storingData', data);

            app.ajax.calendar.store(data, function (response) {
                app.logger.debug('storeEvent', response);

                var newEvent = _.pick(response, ["id", "className", "start", "end", "pause", "site_id", "profile_id", "employee_id", "title"]);

                // app.models[app.metadata.route].totalMinutes = 120;

                fullcalendarScope.removeEvents([event.id]);
                fullcalendarScope.renderEvent(newEvent, false);
                fullcalendarScope.updateTotalDisplayedTime();

            });
        };

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        $fullCalendar.editEvent = function (event) {

            if(moment(event.start).unix() < moment().add(app.metadata.server_offset,'milliseconds').unix()){
                return;
            }
            app.models.manageSchedules.currentSchedule = _.clone(event);
            app.models.manageSchedules.popupShown = true;
        };

        $fullCalendar.updateTotalDisplayedTime = function () {
            var self = this;
            var displayedEvents = this.clientEvents(function(event){
                if(event.start >= self.view.start && event.start <= self.view.end)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            });

            app.models[app.metadata.route].totalMinutes = _.sumBy(displayedEvents, a=>moment(a.end).diff(moment(a.start), 'minutes'));
        };


        var calendarSources = require('../calendarSources');

        $fullCalendar.addEventSource(calendarSources.schedules);
        $fullCalendar.addEventSource(calendarSources.holidays);
    }
};
</script>
```

Okay, so as you can see, I have tree files. Selectw.vue is a component that actually defines the basic format of my listboxes. Then, you have component.js which defines the k-combobox component. This specific component is where the lists are actually populated. Right now, they're filled when the page is actually loaded. This component is also what's ultimately used on the main page (main.vue).

The lists emit an event (update:value) when their value changes and I've been able to catch it on the main page and subsequently call a script that retrieves the values I need in the database (see siteUpdateValue function). The thing is that from there, I can't access the list's content. Where I could access the list's content would be in the k-combobox definition, but at this specific place, I can't bind any form of event because there's no template.

So basically, I'm going around in circles right now and I need help figuring out the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any reason you cannot use VueX or an Event Bus? then, you could have the other two lists render based on `this.$store.state.site`.

Comment: The fact you just brought its existence to my attention? ;)